# Create sub xml files?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<Item>
<Field Name="Filename">x1</Field>
<Field Name="Year">y1</Field>
<Field Name="Name">z1</Field>
</Item>
<Item>
<Field Name="Filename">xn</Field>
<Field Name="Year">yn</Field>
<Field Name="Name">zn</Field>
</Item>
```

For each Item, using PowerShell, I would like to create a xml file with only the information concerning it. How can I do it?

Comment: Is there something you have tried in an effort to do this by chance? We wanted to help improve your code.

Comment: Do you expect your output to be XML as well (header?)

Comment: Yes. With an xml header

Comment: Where possible, with questions like this one, it is important so show you input and expected output. Also it is really important to show us what you have tried. We are here to help you. Not do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know how to proceed in PowerShell. For each Item, I want to create an xml file corresponding to that item, with the same values as in the original, bigger xml database.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab all the `<Item>` nodes with `SelectNodes()`, and then from each one select the `Filename` field with `SelectSingleNode()`:

```
$xml = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<Items>
<Item>
<Field Name="Filename">x1</Field>
<Field Name="Year">y1</Field>
<Field Name="Name">z1</Field>
</Item>
<Item>
<Field Name="Filename">xn</Field>
<Field Name="Year">yn</Field>
<Field Name="Name">zn</Field>
</Item>
</Items>
'@

foreach($item in $xml.SelectNodes('//Item'))
{
    $Filename = $item.SelectSingleNode('//Field[@Name = "Filename"]').InnerText

    # create your new xml document here, import $Item and save to $Filename
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$xml = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<Items>
<Item>
<Field Name="Filename">x1</Field>
<Field Name="Year">y1</Field>
<Field Name="Name">z1</Field>
</Item>
<Item>
<Field Name="Filename">xn</Field>
<Field Name="Year">yn</Field>
<Field Name="Name">zn</Field>
</Item>
</Items>
'@

$xml.Items.Item | ForEach-Object {
    $filename = $_.SelectSingleNode("Field[@Name='Filename']").innertext
    $file = New-Object xml
    $file.InsertBefore($file.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0","UTF-8","yes"),$file.DocumentElement) | Out-Null
    $file.AppendChild($file.ImportNode($_,$true)) | Out-Null
    $file.Save("C:\users\frode\Desktop\$($filename).xml")
}
```